# How do I send an image to the output in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, web

I want to open my servlet which basically checks my permissions and if allowed, shows me a picture like it would be a real jpeg. My code so far:

```
File file = new File("C:/test.jpeg");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
byte imageBytes[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
response.setContentLength(imageBytes.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(imageBytes);
response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

But somehow the image it tries to show me in the browser is corrupted. I already checked that the file exists, as the image.length is not zero. What did I do wrong?

Comment: *Unrelated:* JSP is a text template for generating the response, so you don't use JSP for responding with pure binary data, like an image, you do that in a Servlet. JSP != Servlet, so keep your terminology straight.

Comment: Where in that code do you believe that you're reading the content of the file into the byte array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start using the newer [NIO.2 File API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) that was added in Java 7, mostly the [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class, because it makes the job much easier.

*Option 1:* Load file into byte[]

```java
byte[] imageBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:/test.jpeg"));

response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
response.setContentLength(imageBytes.length);
try (OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
    out.write(imageBytes);
}
```

*Option 2:* Stream the file without using a lot of memory (recommended)

```java
Path imageFile = Paths.get("C:/test.jpeg");
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
response.setContentLength((int) Files.size(imageFile));
try (OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
    Files.copy(imageFile, out);
}
```